# How can I link ISSET process page with Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, email

I want to **send mail** using **php** and **elastic mail** config:
The two codes work very well when i use submit form that call **senEmail** function directly like this.

forgot.php

```php
    <form onsubmit="sendEmail()";>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="submit" value="Vérifier">
    </form>
```

sendEmail script

```php
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <script>
        function sendEmail(){
            Email.send({
                Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
                Username : "test@gmail.com",
                Password : "57AC71719A",
                Port : "2525",
                To : document.getElementById("email").value,
                From : 'test@gmail.com',
                Subject : "This is the subject",
                Body : "message body here",
            }).then(
            message => alert(message)
            );
        }
    </script>
```

So far it works very well the mail is sent

Now I want to add more conditions like if the mail doesn't exist in DB and more detail, for that I want to link the submit form to another process page.
This is what I change in the form of forgot.php page :

```php
    <form action="forgot.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
       <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
       <input type="submit" name="forgot_password" value="Vérifier">
    </form>
```

This form call that page :

```php
    if (isset($_POST['forgot_password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    $emailCheckQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $emailCheckResult = mysqli_query($con, $emailCheckQuery);

    // if query run
    if ($emailCheckResult) {
        // if email matched
        if (mysqli_num_rows($emailCheckResult) > 0) {
            $code = rand(999999, 111111);
            $updateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_users SET code = $code WHERE email = '$email'";
            $updateResult = mysqli_query($con, $updateQuery);
            if ($updateResult) {


   // here how can I call sendEmail function ?
                
                
            }
        }else{
            $errors['invalidEmail'] = "Adresse e-mail invalide";
        }
    }else {
        $errors['db_error'] = "Échec lors de la vérification des e-mails de la base de données !";
    }
```

Comment: are you aware that your exposing the smtp / API details to the client and the if an attacker enters `0' OR 1=1;--` as the email address they can then set the code on everyone's account and then use that code to possibly login or lockout any account, presuming your using the code as some kind of password

Comment: You could try putting the code in, to send the email. And if it doesn't work, someone will correct it.